# Is there an 'offical' way to store data in uTouch-Apps?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

through qml there are several ways to store data. Is there any 'offical' way to store data in Ubuntu-Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there are any 'official' ways as off yet, the platform is so young things like this are still being worked on.

I am currently working on SQLite for UTouch and a "SimpleStore" for more basic things like JSON objects and strings etc.

Short answer, no, not yet.